# How to get all of my Issues in my Bitbucket repository using the API

Tags: java, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am using Java and made a get Request via `Unirest.get` (see the code below).

The code works fine, but I have one big problem: I do not get all of my Issues, only 20 of them.

Can you please tell me why I don't get all of them?

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(Unirest.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/issues")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            .header("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            .asJson());
System.out.println(json);
```

When I copy the output in a *.json* file I don't get all of my Issues as I expected.

Comment: maybe include (part of) the response payload in your question? is there some paging going on? or check the docs, if there is a request parameter to specify response size or page number?

Comment: The Api says that  I will get all of my Issues in my Issue Tracker without editing a parameter if I make this get Request.

If i use a queyString and filter by a specific Issue I get this one Issue, but when I excecute my code The Issue is not in the json output.

I aslo tried to set a limit but dont work

Comment: u are right, with a pagination the code works fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/issues#get) state that there's a parameter `pagelen` which has this description:

> Current number of objects on the existing page. The **default value is**
>   **10** with 100 being the maximum allowed value. Individual APIs may
>   enforce different values.

So it seems like there's pagination going on, you can either set this `pagelen` to be larger, or you can get the `next` property which is a URI to the next page of objects and load the remaining objects that way.

Example url with `pagelen` of 100 [inspired by this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-can-I-get-page-2-with-a-pagelen-100-when-querying-a-list-of/qaq-p/618720):

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/issues?pagelen=100
```